# Bot is not working fine due luis api exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a bot made in framework v4 using c#.it is using luis in it. It was working fine before but now it is giving error like
Sorry, it looks like something went wrong: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’
It is issue related with luis. Plez any can help me. I am also attaching the trace coming in emulator

```
Source: "Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS"
```

StackTrace: " at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.ResolveWithHttpMessagesAsync(String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.ResolveAsync(IPrediction operations, String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizerOptionsV2.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, HttpClient httpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizerOptionsV2.cs:line 72
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, LuisRecognizerOptions predictionOptions, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 467
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 173
 at LuminousSaathiBot.Bots.SaathiDialogBot`1.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\LuminousSaathiBot\LuminousSaathiBot\Bots\SaathiDialogBot.cs:line 40
 at LuminousSaathiBot.Middleware.HandoffMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken ct) in C:\LuminousSaathiBot\LuminousSaathiBot\Middleware\HandoffMiddleware.cs:line 147
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions.CatchExceptionMiddleware`1.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\LuminousSaathiBot\LuminousSaathiBot\Middleware\CatchExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 34"
valueType: "APIErrorException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something's wrong with your LUIS AppId or Subscription Key. You need to get these from the Manage section in LUIS, as shown below. Where you use these exactly, depends on how you configure your LUIS services in your Bot.

[image: App ID]

[image: Subscription Key]

Comment: @Hiliton Giesenow , i think their is somethings wrong with quota or starter key...do you have idea about it?

Comment: In terms of quota, how many calls are you making? In terms of starter key, how are you configuring your Luis endpoint in your application?

Comment: Hilton is correct. There is a 1000 calls per month quota on the starter key, so if you're still using that, and getting 'Forbidden', you've hit that quota, and should upgrade your resource key. information on quotas are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#key-limits You'll find that if you search stackoverflow for 'LUIS bot forbidden', this comes up frequently.